# Serializing epoch time long as date string using JsonFormat

Tags: jackson

I've found a great many answers for deserializing, but none for the other way around.

Let's say i have this simple example class:

```
public class MyLogEntry {
    long timestamp;

    public MyLogEntry() {}
}
```

Now i want to serialize this using jackson and turn this timestamp in epoch time into a date string, for example "2020-05-08T09:17:15.154Z". I could do this by adding a getter method with the @JsonProperty tag, but i was wondering if this is possibly in a simpler way using JsonFormat instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
```

Of course you'd have to change your timestamp to java.util.Date().
https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html

You could also write a custom serializer, but that would probably be overkill in this case.